# sorting in std::map where key is a std::string

Tags: c++, stl

I have a std::map  mymap

Now, if I insert values in the map like:

```
std::map <string, string> mymap;
mymap["first"] = "hi";
mymap["third"] = "how r you";
mymap["second"] = "hello";
```

Now I want to iterate over the map and print the value in sorted(keys) manner:

```
map<string, string>::iterator itr;
for(itr = mymap.begin(); itr != mymap.end(); itr++)
{
   string newline = itr->second;
   cout << newline << endl;
}
```

Output should be:

```
hi 
hello 
how r you
```

I thought that by default map stores in sorted keys manner but I'm getting the same order in output as I'm giving in input. Do I need to provide my sort function for this or need to do something extra before iterating over the map?

Comment: The for loop refers to `file_line` and not `mymap`. I take it this is not the actual code as `first` is not quoted in population of `mymap`.

Comment: I am not quite sure about the C++ std::map implementation, but such hashtables are not usually sorted. They are meant to be accessed via indexer, not traversed.

Comment: @user983064 std::map is a binary tree, ordered by key. C++11 has hash tables, such as std::unordered_map.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The elements in `std::map` are ordered (by default) by `operator<` applied to the key.

The code you posted, with minor edits, worked for me as you expected:

```
std::map <string, string> mymap;
mymap["first"]="hi";
mymap["third"]="how r you";
mymap["second"]="hello";

for (std::map<string, string>::iterator i = mymap.begin(); i != mymap.end(); i++)
{
    cout << i->second << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
hi
hello
how r you
```

Comment: uhmmmm ... what about "fourth"?? Should it be after "first" or "third"?

May be he needs to customize the comparison predicate...

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia, yes he would or just use an `int` as the key.

Comment: `auto`? this question wasn't tagged as [tag:C++11]

Comment: @julio.alegria, there you go.

Comment: Just a follow-up question on this response, what is the difference between `for (std::map<string, string>::iterator i = mymap.begin(); i != mymap.end(); i++)` and `for (std::map<string, string>::iterator i = mymap.begin(); i != mymap.end(); ++i)` where the iterator is incremented before rather than after?

Comment: @MosesKirathe The former increments i by 1 at the 'end' of each iteration whereas the latter increments i by 1 at the 'beginning' of each iteration.

Answer (score 9):

The `map` is actually a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), and is sorted by KEY order. You are printing `itr->second` which is the VALUE not the KEY. If you want your key/value pairs sorted by VALUE, use the VALUE as key instead, or store everything in another container (say an array), then sort them.

Comment: What you said is correct, so KEYS are: `"first" < "second" < "third"`, thus, we should expect the same result as the OP said: `hi | hello | how r you`, but he said: _I'm getting the same order in output as I'm giving in input_, that is: `hi | how r you | hello`.

Answer (score 4):

std::map is already ordered.  If you were using unordered_map, now you'd have a problem!

Entries in std::map are ordered by the key, or itr->first.  itr->second as you have it, refers to the value associated with the key.

Further more, you're not iterating over the map, you're iterating over file_line (I don't know what that is, but I'm going to assume it's different from mymap.  That is what you should be iterating over).

Answer (score 2):

The standard defines:

> The fundamental property of iterators of associative containers is that they iterate through the containers
>   in the non-descending order of keys where non-descending is defined by the comparison that was used to
>   construct them.