# Calculate overlapping times inside a map C++

Tags: c++, time, dictionary, overlapping

I have a map with key = startTime and value = endTime, like this:

```
map<uint32_t,uint32_t>time_map;
```

(being `uint32_t` is `unsigned __int32`, but this is not relevant here).

I want to calculate how many of overlapping values are there among this values (that represent startTime for a connection and endTime of it, so actually how many overlapping connections are there).

Which is the fastest way to calculate this? is there any function/method inside `std::map` thought to solve this kind of problem?

---

Edit: As far as the original question is unclear, the idea is to calculate the maximum number of overlapping connections at any given point in time. This means, given these times:

```
start 100 - end 1000 / start 120 - end 200 / start 250 - end 400 / start 600 - end 800
```

the answer is 2 (1 with 2, 1 with 3, 1 with 4, but none of the others with each other)

Comment: Simply testing against each other (O(n^2)) is too slow? How many entries are in the map. And: Should this really be a map, or is an `vector<pair<uint32_t,uint32_t>>` enough?

Comment: @MatthiasB Right now is a map because I consider to add some more data inside the value apart from the time, not relevant now.
It is too slow and it is not only iterate, the problem is considering the minimum range shared by all the entries that overlap (this is not the same than just comparing start-endTime from one time with all the other, from my point of view). I don't know if it is clear, is a little bit hard to explain, but just comparing all with each other generate more results than reality (not all times considered as overlapped are overlapped with all the other times)

Comment: So you need to find common intersection of all overlapped intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a naive approach first, using a side-table; it will be close to a sweeping line algorithm.

The idea:

- iterate through the connections in order (ordered by start time here)
- keeping a set of the currently involved connections

The trick is to keep track of the connections efficiently, and especially of when to remove them; a priority-queue is great for this.

Some help:

```
struct Connection {
    uint32_t start;
    uint32_t end;
}; // struct Connection

// WATCH OUT:
// std::priority_queue only let you access the MAXIMUM element, so the predicate
// is the OPPOSITE of what we usually write...
struct OrderByEnd {
    bool operator()(Connection const& left, Connection const& right) const {
        if (left.end > right.end) { return true; }
        if (left.end < right.end) { return false; }
        return left.start > right.start;
    }
}; // struct OrderByEnd

using CurrentlyOverlappingType = std::priority_queue<Connection, std::deque<Connection>, OrderByEnd>;
```

And then, we sweep:

```
size_t countMaxNumberOfOverlaps(std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t> const& connections) {
    if (connections.empty()) { return 0; }

    size_t max = 0;
    CurrentlyOverlappingType currentlyOverlapping;

    for (auto const& con: connections) {
        // Purge no longer overlapping connections
        while (not currentlyOverlapping.empty() and currentlyOverlapping.top().end < con.first) {
            currentlyOverlapping.pop();
        }

        // Debug:
        if (not currentlyOverlapping.empty()) {
            std::cout << "[" << con.first << ", " << con.second <<
                "] is overlapping with: " << currentlyOverlapping.size() << " connections\n";
        }

        // The current connection is necessarily overlapping with itself
        currentlyOverlapping.push(Connection{con.first, con.second});

        max = std::max(max, currentlyOverlapping.size());
    }

    return max;
} // countMaxNumberOfOverlaps
```

And [it works as expected](http://ideone.com/ypCaT0):

```
[120, 200] is overlapping with: 1 connections
[250, 400] is overlapping with: 1 connections
[600, 800] is overlapping with: 1 connections
Max number of overlaps: 2
```

The complexity is harder to fathom. You have to sweep through the whole set of connections, but at each step the amount of work is proportional to the current number of overlapping connections...

- Worst case complexity: O(N * log(N)) I would say (because inserting in the priority queue is logarithmic)
- Average case complexity: O(N * log(O)) where O is the number of overlapping connections

Note: in the algorithmic analysis, I considered that the complexity of the purge part is amortized constant; we know items are going to be purged, so we can account for their purge in the cost of their insertion. N items are inserted, N items are going to be purged. The number of comparisons executed as part of the purge process is (I think) also amortized constant (the total for all items being bounded by a maximum of 2N) although it's intuition and not computation. And therefore, the cost of the purge is dwarfed by the cost of inserting the items in the priority queue, which log(O) per item.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is one of line segment intersection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley-Ottmann_algorithm), if you view time intervals as 1-dimensional `line segments` (rather than the usual 2-dimensional line segments in Euclidean plane).

Algorithmically, you can use one of the sweep-line algorithms in computational geometry to achieve complexity that is less than O(n^2) associated with the naive approach. The Bentley–Ottmann algorithm above is one of them. Conceptually, you maintain a sweep line scanning from left to right, keep a record of your scan-line entering or leaving intervals. Details can be found in any good computational geometry text books.

I don't think `std::map` support sweep line algorithms, and you will need to implement the necessary data structure associated with it.

Comment: I think you are right, this seems to be an interesting approach! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Boost's Date/Time library.  It has a time_period class which supports an intersects method as shown in these [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.time_math).  This removes the need for you to write code for 'do these two intervals overlap?' although you will still have to decide how to traverse your collection (avoiding an O(n^2) traverse seems difficult).

EDIT : you need the maximum number of concurrent intervals at any time.
In which case, Ting L's suggestion of a sweep-line algorithm seems best.  Sort the intervals by start time and iterate over them in order.  Maintain a stack as you iterate along.  For each new interval, pop any intervals on the stack that have expired before the new interval starts.  Keeping track of the maximum size of the stack will give you the maximum number of concurrent intervals (if you need to know which intervals they are, you will have to maintain a separate container 'current longest set' updated as you iterate)

Comment: You are right, I think there is no other way to do it, I should sweep over all the values and find the intervals. Anyway, the difficult still resides on determine the unique overlapping with some elements with each others to avoid extra counts (and the opposite). I will try with this approach, maybe I can find a proper solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Map (std map) is a tree sorted by key. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490359/sorting-in-stdmap-where-key-is-a-stdstring) link. So if you iterate through, then you would get it by order of start-time. However, beyond that to check for specific overlapping time, there would be no additional support from the std::map api.

Now to check the overlap time, you have to do classical iterator approach as the worse case method. Check the end time of a element `i`, is always less than the start time of `i` to `N` .

HTH!

Comment: That was my first approach, iterating every element and then comparing to each other. The problem is that this calculates more  than real results, for example:
Start 100 End 1000 / Start 120 End 300 / Start 320 End 600 / Start 650 End 800
Will say that there are 4 overlapping connections, but actually there are only 2.
I have tried updating the max/min time everytime I consider a new overlapping time, but then I don't know if I cover all the cases...

Comment: is it just double counting the number of overlaps? e.g. first overlaps with second and second overlaps with first, so contributes two overlaps?

Comment: I guess the inner loop should only run from the current element to the end, instead of start to end.

Comment: "Actually there are only 2" - which two? Did not catch. First is overlapping with 3 others, not? Or you mean that 3 others are actually one experiment which started/stopped.

Comment: Hmm, in that example, all the overlaps are : 1 overlaps with 2, 1 overlaps with 3 and 1 overlaps with 4.  Should that be three instances of overlap?  Or should it be four intervals which are part of overlaps?  Depends how you count it.

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths Exactly, I think I have expressed badly, what I mean is how to calculate the maximum overlapping (concurrent) sessions for all those considered times. In my previous example, the answer would be 2 (and not 4), so the point is not to count which is the connections that overlaps with more of the other, but the maximum number of real connections that were "alive" at the same time, based on this time data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the nature of the problem is connected with sets and sets intersections. You can try STL [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) container and [set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) function which effectively finds intersections of two sorted sequences. (Really, set is just a map with only keys (without values) so you can work with maps, they are sorted too.)

Say, you can represent time interval as a pair(start, end) and build an intersection of all intervals intersecting sets. You can define your own Compare function.
The exact logic would follow from the details of your task, which are not fully clear.

(There are also `set_difference`, `set_union`, and `set_symmetric_difference` functions.)